# Why does this wobble?

Tags: processing

Tested on Processing 2.2.1 & 3.0a2 on OS X.

The code I've tweaked below may look familiar to some of you, it's what Imgur now uses as their loading animation. It was posted on OpenProcessing.org and I've been able to get it working in Processing, but the arcs are constantly wobbling around (relative movement within 1 pixel). I'm new to Processing and I don't see anything in the sketch that could be causing this, it runs in ProcessingJS without issue (though very high CPU utilization).

```java
int num = 6;

float step, spacing, theta, angle, startPosition;

void setup() {
  frameRate( 60 );
  size( 60, 60 );
  strokeWeight( 3 );
  noFill();
  stroke( 51, 51, 51 );
  step = 11;
  startPosition = -( PI / 2 );
}

void draw() {
  background( 255, 255, 255, 0 );
  translate( width / 2, height / 2 );
  for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
    spacing = i * step;
    angle = ( theta + ( ( PI / 4 / num ) * i ) ) % PI;
    float arcEnd = map( sin( angle ), -1, 1, -TWO_PI, TWO_PI );
    if ( angle <= ( PI / 2 )  ) {
      arc( 0, 0, spacing, spacing, 0 + startPosition , arcEnd + startPosition  );
    }
    else {
      arc( 0, 0, spacing, spacing, TWO_PI - arcEnd + startPosition , TWO_PI + startPosition  );
    }
  }
  arc( 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, TWO_PI );
  theta += .02;
}
```

If it helps, I'm trying to export this to an animated GIF. I tried doing this with ProcessingJS and jsgif, but hit some snags. I'm able to get it exported in Processing using gifAnimation just fine.

**UPDATE**

Looks like I'm going with `hint( ENABLE_STROKE_PURE );`, cleaned up with  `strokeCap( SQUARE );` within `setup()`. It doesn't look the same as the original but I do like the straight edges. Sometimes when you compromise, the result ends up even better than the "ideal" solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your doubt. The animation basically comes from incrementing theta `theta += .02` each frame. It's used to calc the angle used in defining the arc. Sin and cos are also known as ["circular functions"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularFunctions.html)... So the angle when reaches 360º kind of wraps arround.

Comment: @v.k. the arcs "shake" around, which is not something I defined in the code but happens anyway

Comment: I see in 2.0.1 it works fine. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the problem on 2.2.1 for OS X, and calling `hint(ENABLE_STROKE_PURE)` in `setup()` fixes it for me. I couldn't find good documentation for this call, though; it's just something that gets mentioned here and there.

As for the root cause, if I absolutely had to speculate, I'd guess that Processing's Java renderer approximates a circular arc using a spline with a small number of control points. The control points are spaced out between the endpoints, so as the endpoints move, so do the bumps in the approximation. The approximation might be good enough for a single frame, but the animation makes the bumps obvious. Setting `ENABLE_STROKE_PURE` might increase the number of control points, or it might force Processing to use a more expensive circular arc primitive in the underlying graphics library it's built upon. Again, though, this is just a guess as to why a drawing environment might have a bug like the one you've seen. I haven't read Processing's source code to verify the guess.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps with the shaking, but do you see the blobs that occur when the arcs close now?

Comment: Yep, I see that too. I think that's caused by the arcs being almost-but-not-quite closed. The renderer draws a circular cap on both ends of the arc, and these caps overlap. In theory that shouldn't be a problem, but the renderer probably double-paints the overlapping subpixels. You can fix that with `smooth(0)`, but the result is ugly. Or you could change the line styles with `strokeCap(SQUARE)`. Maybe the ideal solution would be to rewrite the timing of the arcs so that they don't linger in the almost-closed state.

Comment: Great, I will have a play around with those options. I think you're right about the overlapping subpixels, that's what I thought when I saw it. Good enough for most animations but for something as intimate as 6 arcs it's very visible.