# Processing animation very jittery

Tags: animation, processing, procedural-generation

I'm just tinkering around with Processing in order to make some `.gif` animations procedurally. For some reason, the one I just finished making has a lot of jitter when I run it (and also when I export it using GifAnimation). I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

Excuse the hack-job that is my code:

```
long lastTime = 0;
float angle1, angle2, angle3, angle4, angle5, angle6;
int change;
public void setup() {
  size(120, 120);
  lastTime = millis();
  angle1 = -60;
  angle2 = 240;
  angle3 = -30;
  angle4 = 210; 
  angle5 = -75;
  angle6 = 255;    
  change = 3;

  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(10);  
  smooth();
}
public void draw() {

  if (millis() - lastTime > 12) {
    background(255,255,255);
    lastTime = millis();    

    stroke(#3aa8c3);
    arc(60, 60, 70, 70, radians(angle1), radians(angle2));
    ellipse(60, 60, 10, 10);

    stroke(#e7e7e7);
    arc(60, 60, 40, 40, radians(angle3), radians(angle4));
    arc(60, 60, 100, 100, radians(angle5), radians(angle6));

    angle1-=change*2;
    angle2-=change*2;
    angle3+=change*3;
    angle4+=change*3;
    angle5+=change;
    angle6+=change;

    }
}
```

The result is the following:
[image: jittery gif]

Is it something I'm doing wrong, or is it simply a restriction of the Processing environment?

Edit:
After changing the rendering mode to P3D (`size(120, 120, P3D);`) things are working a lot more smoothly. It got rid of the rounded edges and I had to add some anti-aliasing (`smooth(8)`), but it no longer jitters. The transparent background is also a bonus:
[image]

Comment: It could be low-quality antialiasing. Perhaps give [`smooth(8)`](https://processing.org/reference/smooth_.html) a try?

Comment: I just changed the rendering mode to `P3D`, and the jitter is fixed. It got rid of the rounded ends and anti-aliasing, but that command makes it look a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this wobble?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194697/why-does-this-wobble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better luck if you post the simplest form of your problem, something like this:

```
public void setup() {
  size(360, 360);
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  smooth(10);
}
public void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(#3aa8c3);
  arc(60, 60, 70, 70, radians(mouseX), radians(mouseY));
}
```

This allows us to eliminate causes and more easily find the solution.

Also, I googled "processing arc jittery" and "processing arc wobble" and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194697/why-does-this-wobble) answer, which says to try the `hint(ENABLE_STROKE_PURE)` function. When I add that to the example, it seems to work much better:

```
public void setup() {
  size(360, 360);
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  smooth(10);
  hint(ENABLE_STROKE_PURE);
}
public void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(#3aa8c3);
  arc(60, 60, 70, 70, radians(mouseX), radians(mouseY));
}
```

Adding `hint(ENABLE_STROKE_PURE);` as the last line in your `setup()` function also seems to fix your problem.